# Espresso Tests not able to click DialogButton on certain devices

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have an Espresso-Test for verifying a dialog being displayed. It presses a button to open the dialog and should dismiss it by clicking the dialog's positive button. The dialog opens fine but clicking the positive button of the dialog fails on two Samsung-devices (Samsung S6 Edge and Samsung S7), but works on all others. I've tried the following solutions:

Matching the button by the text that should be on the button
`onView(withText(R.string.changelog_ok_button)).perform(click())`

Matching the button by the ID assigned to positive dialog buttons by the android OS:
`onView(withId(android.R.id.button1)).perform(click())`

Both solutions work on most devices, but said Samsungs refuse to perform the click, delivering the following error:

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click' on view 'with string from resource id: <2131755113>[changelog_ok_button] value: OK'.
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
at least 90 percent of the view's area is displayed to the user.
Target view: "AppCompatButton{id=16908313, res-name=button1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=192, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@ab3a33, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=666.0, y=12.0, text=OK, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"
```

What is most confusing is that, when I use the Layout Inspector, the ID of the Button is `R.id.button1` and it's text is also matching with `R.string.changelog_ok_button`.

Is there anything Samsung does different for dialogs that could be causing this? Did someone have the same problem and found a solution or has some ideas how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

It is clear based on the error description:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints: at least 90 percent of the view's area is displayed to the user.
```

So, I guess that the problematic devices have smaller screen resolution where button view is cut or hidden a bit, so the view area shown to the user is below 90%.

Comment: I had the devices locally on my machine to test that. The Button is fully visible and manually clickable (as it should. Dialog-Buttons should never leave the displayed area).